# Select columns instead of rows in shiny with DT::datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am building a Shiny gadget and I want to select columns instead rows in a DT::datatable. At [the documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) it is said that it should be done in the following way. (It is also applied in [this example](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html).)

```
library(shiny); library(DT)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('iris')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$iris <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, selection = list(target = 'column')
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However this throws the following error `Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`. This makes sense if we look in the documentation of `datatable()`, it states that `selection` should be a character ("the row selection mode (single or multiple selection or disable selection) when a table widget is rendered in a Shiny app").

So how should I allow for selecting columns instead of rows? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of `DT` are you using? The footer on the bottom of [this page](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-selection/) states *"DT (>= 0.1.26) is required to run this example."*. The CRAN version of `DT` is `0.1`; running `devtools::install_github("Rstudio/DT")` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!